# Syntax of `sep =` as separator

Tags: r, label

I would like to understand how is the syntax of the command `sep =`. Below, I report an example code:

```
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggplot2)


formula <- y ~ x + I(x^2)
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_fit_deviations(formula = formula, colour = "red") +
  stat_poly_line(formula = formula) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label =  paste(stat(eq.label), stat(adj.rr.label), sep = "*\", \"*")),
               formula = formula)
```

I understand that `sep = "*\", \"*"` is aiming to add a comma between `eq.label` and `adj.rr.label`. There is no reference on the guide of `stat_poly_eq`, I would like to understand the meaning of `"*\"` and `\"*"`, perhaps learning something more to change this configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels you create in `stat_poly_eq` are character strings. They are parsed into expressions, which in turn are converted into plotmath symbols. You can get a feel for how this works if you do:

```r
plot(1:10, type = 'n')
text(5, 5, label = expression(paste(y~`=`~3*italic(x)^2*", "*R^2)))
```

[image]

All the `sep` is doing in your case is providing a separating comma and space between the formula and the R squared. You can change this to anything you like as long as it parses correctly to a valid plotmath expression:

```r
formula <- y ~ x + I(x^2)
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_fit_deviations(formula = formula, colour = "red") +
  stat_poly_line(formula = formula) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label =  paste(stat(eq.label), stat(adj.rr.label), 
                                  sep = "*\" is the formula, and the R squared is \"*")),
               formula = formula)
```

[image]

See `?plotmath` to find out all the things your can do with plotmath expressions